# How to validate that *first* two characters entered are letters?

Tags: javascript, validation, character

I'm looking to check that the first two characters entered in a name field are letters--beyond that it makes no difference (spaces, ', -, etc are all fair game). Here's what I have so far, but it isn't working. Thoughts? Thanks!

```
if (document.form01.firstName.value.length < 2 
 || !/^[a-zA-Z]{2}+.?$/.test(document.form01.firstName.value)) {
    alert("First name must contain at least 2 letters.");
    document.form01.firstName.select();
    document.form01.firstName.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
    return false;    // leave now
}
```

Comment: Just a note:  you don't need the length check.  If the regex matches, then you will already know you have at least two letters.  (You also don't need to match the rest of the string; `/^[a-zA-Z]{2}/` would be enough.)

Comment: All that aside, though...are there any error messages in your JS console?

Comment: if (!/^[a-zA-Z]{2}/.test(document.form01.firstName.value)) {
        alert("First name must contain at least 2 letters.");
        document.form01.firstName.select();
        document.form01.firstName.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        return false;    // leave now
    }

Comment: No--just that password fields are present in a form with insecure (http://) form action. But that's unrelated to this name field

Answer (score 1):

Your expression has what appears to be a syntax error.  The `+` doesn't have anything to require one-or-more of, and JS doesn't do super-greedy matches -- it supports `?` following a quantifier to make the expression ungreedy, but not `+`.  You should be getting a SyntaxError or the like.  (If you're not, the browser might be interpreting the `+` literally and expecting a `+`.)

You could change the expression to `/^[a-zA-Z]{2}.?$/` to get rid of that error...but note also that it won't match if there's punctuation *within* the string -- it'll only match a single non-letter at the end.

You'd do better to only try to match what you care about.  In this case, since you only care that the first two characters are letters, `/^[a-zA-Z]{2}/` would avoid the issue entirely.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function digitVal(elem){
  
  if (!elem.value.match(/\d{2,2}/)){
    // if the first two characters are not digits
    
    elem.style.background = 'yellow';
    // the background changes to yellow
    
    }
  
  else {
    
    elem.style.background = 'white';
    // otherwise leave it white
    
    }
  
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="digitVal(this)" size="40" placeholder="first two characters must be numbers"/>
```